# Problema com POST no Angular

Tags: angular, post, httpclient

Estou montando um sistema de login em Angular. O back-end é em cakePHP. A requisição de *preflight* está sendo feita corretamente e recebendo o status 200 (figura abaixo). Após o preflight, o angular manda a requisição POST vazia, sem os parâmetros de login. Se eu fico repetindo a requisição, as vezes ele envia a requisição correta. 
A minha função que faz a requisição é a seguinte:

```
SignIn(email = "", password = ""): Observable<Response> {
  const api = environment.apiURL + "login";
  const body = { email, password };
  const options = { headers: this.headers };
  return this.http.post<any>(api, body, options).pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(
      (success) => this.processLogin(success)
      error => console.error(error)
    )
  );}
```

No console ele me diz que foi um problema com o CORS, mas no cakePHP está habilitado e como as vezes a requisição funciona corretamente, eu acredito que o problema seja com o angular. 
Alguém faz ideia do que estou fazendo errado?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema modificando um pouco meu header.
Antes eu usava

```
headers = new HttpHeaders({
Accept: "application/json",
"Content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Quando eu modifiquei para:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders({
Accept: "application/json ; text/plain",
"Content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Aí ele começou a funcionar 100%. Se alguém souber porque isso funcionou e quiser nos explicar, é bem vindo.